# Можно ли создать UML - диаграмму в NetBeans 8.1 IDE ПО ГОТОВОМУ КОДУ

Tags: ide, netbeans, uml

Здравствуйте. Есть готовый проект. С использованием плагина выводится неправильно. 
Почему-то не выводятся связи (наследование от JApplet и ActionListener). Не выводятся стрелочки , почему так? Вот код:

```
package keyboard_app;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ScreenKeyboard extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
   String row1[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","Backspace"};
   String row2[] = {"Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","Enter"};
   String row3[] = {"A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L",":","Shift"};
   String row4[] = {"Z","X","C","V","B","N","M",",",".","?","Spacebar"};
   JButton first[];

   JButton second[];
   JButton third[];
   JButton fourth[];
   JTextArea ta;
   private boolean shiftPressed = false;

   public void init(){
      ta = new JTextArea();
      ta.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); 
      JLabel l = new JLabel("Enter your message here:" );
      l.setFont(new Font("TimesNewRoman",Font.BOLD,14));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      JPanel jpNorth = new JPanel();
      JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel();
      JPanel jpButtons = new JPanel();

      add(jpNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(jpCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(jpButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      jpNorth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      jpNorth.add(l, BorderLayout.WEST);
      jpNorth.add(l, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      jpCenter.setLayout( new BorderLayout());
      jpCenter.add(ta, BorderLayout.WEST);
      jpCenter.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      jpButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

       first = new JButton[row1.length];
       JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row1.length));
       for(int i = 0; i < row1.length; i++) 
       {
        JButton bt = new JButton(row1[i]);
        bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
        first[i] = bt;
        p.add(first[i]);
       }
       jpButtons.add(p);

       second = new JButton[row2.length];
       p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row2.length));
       for(int i = 0; i < row2.length; i++) 
       {
        second[i] = new JButton(row2[i]);
        p.add(second[i]);
       }
       jpButtons.add(p);

       third = new JButton[row3.length];
       p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row3.length));
       for(int i = 0; i < row3.length; i++)
       {
        third[i] = new JButton(row3[i]);
        p.add(third[i]);
       }
       jpButtons.add(p);

       fourth = new JButton[row4.length];
       p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, row4.length));
       for(int i = 0; i < row4.length; ++i)
       {
        fourth[i] = new JButton(row4[i]);
        p.add(fourth[i]);
       }
       jpButtons.add(p);

       for(JButton bt : first)
           bt.addActionListener(this); 
       for(JButton bt : second)
           bt.addActionListener(this); 
       for(JButton bt : third)
           bt.addActionListener(this); 
       for(JButton bt : fourth)
           bt.addActionListener(this); 
   }            
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
          String ac = ae.getActionCommand();
          String text;
          switch (ac) {
            case "Enter":
                ta.setText(ta.getText() + "\n");
                break;
           case "Spacebar":
                ta.setText(ta.getText() + " ");
                break;
            case "Backspace":
                text = ta.getText();
                ta.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
                break;
            case "Shift":
                shiftPressed = (shiftPressed) ? false : true;
             break;
        default:
            text = String.valueOf(ac);
            text = (shiftPressed) ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
            ta.setText(ta.getText() + text);
            break;
    }
} 
}
```

А вот мои действия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так можно это как- то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем ответ найден. Во первых надо устанавливать специальный плагин, их различные модификации свободно можно найти в интернете. То,что "нету стрелочек" - нормально, ведь JApplet - э
то класс стандартной библиотеки.